# How to get values of choicefield using raw query from Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to get values of choicefield from the table of a database using raw query. Instead of getting the values, I got a notification

> NameError was unhandled by user code.

Any help would be appreciated.

**forms.py**

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):

    def get_names():
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        get_query = str("SELECT distinct name from T_STUDENT")

        cursor.execute(get_query)
        results = cursor.fetchall()
        names = []
        i=0
        for row in results:
            names[i]=row[0]
            i+=1
        return names

    def names():
        data = get_names()
        i=0
        names= []
        for key,value in data:
            names.append(('i',value))
            i+=1
        return names

    validflg = forms.ChoiceField(label=("Names:"),
                                    choices = names(),
                                    widget = forms.Select({'class':'form-control'}))
```

Comment: Post your full traceback.

Answer (score 0):

### Edit:

When you're creating your class, the `names` function is not defined. You have two options: you could create a support function or you could add the logic to the constructor.

Here's what the latter looks like:

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):

    def get_names(self):
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        get_query = str("SELECT distinct name from T_STUDENT")

        cursor.execute(get_query)
        results = cursor.fetchall()
        names = []
        i=0
        for row in results:
            names[i]=row[0]
            i+=1
        return names

    def names(self):
        data = self.get_names()
        i=0
        names= []
        for key,value in data:
            names.append(('i',value))
            i+=1
        return names

    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        self.fields['validflg'] = forms.ChoiceField(label=("Names:"),
                                    choices = self.names(),
                                    widget = forms.Select({'class':'form-control'}))
        super(SearchForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

---

### Original

You have made some basic mistakes in your Python.

```
def names():
```

This needs to include reference to the object itself:

```
def names(self):
```

And then you can't just call methods, you need to attach them to a reference as well. This won't work:

```
data = get_names()
```

But this will:

```
data = self.get_names()
```

Comment: thank you, but how about the parameter of names in form.choicefield?